# use custom border

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins, border

is there any way to use custom border by css or can make by JavaScript or jquery.

i want to use a different style of border.
like we use

```
border-style:dashed;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Are you trying to use something other than what is already provided with css? (solid, dashed, dotted, double, ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with CSS3 you can use border-image, which is what you are looking for. for more information click [here](http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/) - but note, that this is only supported by <strike>very few</strike> good browsers (firefox, safari - maybe opera - but no IE (until some day IE9 comes...)).

EDIT:

if you could give some more information how the border should look like, we could try to do some cross-browser-solution - but the best way is to use border-image... and some not-too-ugly-standard-border-fallback for that dumb piece of software called "IE".

Answer (score 4):

CSS3 can do this, but IE won't support it until IE9.

Check out this link: [CSS3 border images](http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/).